# How to execute UIKit event in AngularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, uikit

I've used the Sortable component from [UIKit](https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/sortable.html) in my website. I've made it work and now I will be using the event to execute something when ever I move an icon. The event is called `change.uk.sortable`.

Using jQuery you can call it by:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sample").on("change.uk.sortable", function () {


    });
});
```

How can I do something like this in AngularJS?

Comment: May be without using jQuery: `document.getElementById('sample').addEventListener('change.uk.sortable', function() {...})`

Comment: @IvanMinakov: I want to use AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a directive (which is more the AngularJS way), or since you have to include jQuery for uiKit, you could just use jQuery, as in your question.

Either way you'll need to wrap in a `$scope.apply()` function if you want to update scope properties.

**Directive version:**

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {    
  $scope.movedItemDirectiveVersion = "No item has been moved yet...";    
});

app.directive("mySortable", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.on('change.uk.sortable.mySortable', function(event, sortableObj, element, action) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.movedItemDirectiveVersion = "You moved " + element[0].innerText;
        });
      });
      // clean up when scope is destroyed
      scope.$on("$destroy",
        function() {
          elem.off("change.uk.sortable.mySortable");
        }
      );
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="uk-sortable uk-grid uk-grid-small uk-grid-width-1-5" data-uk-sortable="" my-sortable>
  <li class="uk-grid-margin" style="">
    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="uk-grid-margin" style="">
    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Non-directive version:**

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.movedItem = "No item has been moved yet...";

  $('#withoutDirective').on("change.uk.sortable", function(event, sortableObj, element, action) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.movedItem = "You moved " + element[0].innerText;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<ul id="withoutDirective" class="uk-sortable uk-grid uk-grid-small uk-grid-width-1-5" data-uk-sortable="">
  <li class="uk-grid-margin" style="">
    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="uk-grid-margin" style="">
    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Demo for both versions: http://jsfiddle.net/s9fr43of/1/

Comment: Hi, this is already OK. But can I just request for one code please. I also want to know where i drop the icon so that I can update the database the new arrangement. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the `saveOrdering` function in https://codepen.io/malles/pen/pvLOyb for the basic idea